# When splitting strings in a list, Python only prints vertically

Tags: python, split

I cut each string in my list in half. I would like to print each half separately, however, when I go to print the first half of the string "have" which is "ha," it prints every first letter in each of my halves. Does anyone know the reason for this?

```
lis = ['have', 'agreat', 'day']


for x in lis:

    first = x[:len(x)//2]
    second = x[len(x)//2:]
    print(first) 
    output>>>
    ha
    agr
    d
    print(first[0])
    output>>>
    h
    a
    d
```

Comment: Because you are printing first[0], instead of second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**
You should add your first and second halfs to different list. Then outside your loop, just use random to join two halfs randomly.

Remember that if you have any logic inside your loop (like your print) it will print for every iteration. That's the reason you are getting h, a, d, because you are printing the first letter of your first half of every word in your list.

```
import random
lis = ['have', 'agreat', 'day']
first = []
second = []
for x in lis:
    first.append(x[:len(x)//2])
    second.append(x[len(x)//2:])
final = random.choice(first) + random.choice(second)
print(final)
```

Output:
`agrve`

---

Actually you're splitting fine, but you're not printing what you want. In your second print, you are printing first[0], which gives you h (have), a (agreat), d (day).

Only change first[0], by second

```
for x in lis:
    first = x[:len(x)//2]
    second = x[len(x)//2:]
    print("List " + x)
    print(first) 
    print(second)
```

Result

```
List have
ha
ve
List agreat
agr
eat
List day
d
ay
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I think it would help to give some more information about what I'm trying to do. I need two groups: one is the first half of each string in my list. The second is the second half of each string in my list. This is because I'm trying to randomly pull a first half (from whichever string) and a second half from another random string. I want to add the two random halves together. I want to be able call each first/second half. For example, "ha" or "agr." However, when I use print(random.choice(first)) I get this "h
 g
 d"

Comment: Can you update your question including an specific example of what you need. I'll help you.

Comment: @Msamericana1 I updated my answer with an explanation and solution.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine:

```
lis = ['have', 'agreat', 'day']  
for x in lis: 
    first = x[:len(x)//2] 
    second = x[len(x)//2:] 
    print(first+'|'+second) 
                                                       
ha|ve
agr|eat
d|ay
```

Answer (score 0):

`first[0]` will print the first letter in the first half of your string.
So if you have `have` and you cut this in half `first = ha`-`second = ve`.
`first[0]` will give you `h`. So I assume you want to print `ha - ve`

```
lis = ['have', 'agreat', 'day']


for x in lis:

    first = x[:len(x)//2]
    second = x[len(x)//2:]
    print(first,'-',second)
```

output

```
ha - ve
agr - eat
d - ay
```